# How to register angular application on eureka server

Tags: angular, spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I have a use case in which I need to register my angular application on spring-cloud eureka server. I found a library, `eureka-js-client`, but am unable to understand where should I put the config.

Also, it has something called `client.start()` and `client.end()` to start and stop sending heartbeats to eureka server, but we use use ng serve to run angular app.

Can someone provide me with the changes I need to make to a hello-world angular project to register it to eureka server?

Comment: best approach is to bundle your Angular with your Spring-boot app and run as spring boot

Comment: Hi,
Any solution for this thing? I also have a requirement for registering Angular App to eureka. Already the backend spring boot java services are registered with Eureka. Now I have to register Angular app to Eureka as well.

Comment: Hi @AchillesVan , any other solution apart from bundling it with spring boot?

Answer (score -2):

Angular runs in the browser. `eureka-js-client` is an node.js server library, so you need to implement some kind of server app which serves you content and registers with eureka.

Comment: OP should have mentioned the angular version, the version you are guessing in your answer is AngularJS